# Pitch accent pattern for verb stem + な

Tags: pronunciation, pitch-accent

I've only ever heard this form be used in the command "待ちな!" (Wait!), but just out of curiosity, I'd like to know what pitch accent rule(s) apply here. I thought I'd heard the above-mentioned phrase be pronounced as まちな{HLL}, but for some reason, that doesn't seem right to me, since this is a shortening of the なさい form, which is always pronounced with a pitch drop on さ. So wouldn't you say まちな{LHH}(さい{HL})? Following that logic, wouldn't you also say 食べな{LHH}?

What rule applies here? Is it the same for all verbs, whether they be accented or unaccented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> this is a shortening of the なさい form, which is always pronounced with a pitch drop on さ. So wouldn't you say [まちな]{LHH}([さい]{HL})? Following that logic, wouldn't you also say [食べな]{LHH}?

You're right. We pronounce the positive imperative 「～～な」 this way:

> [まちな]{LHH}。"Wait!"
>
> [たべな]{LHH}。"Eat (it)!"
>
> [いきな]{LHH}。"Go!"
>
> [みな]{LH}。"Look!"
>
> [あきらめな]{LHHHH}。"Give (it) up!"
>
> [やりな]{LHH}。"Do (it)!"
>
> [しな]{LH}。"Do (it)!"
>
> [べんきょうしな]{LHHHHHH}。"Study!"

We don't pronounce 待ちな as [まちな]{HLL}.

---

> I thought I'd heard the above-mentioned phrase be pronounced as [まちな]{HLL}

Maybe you heard 「待**つ**な」?  The negative imperative 「な」 is pronounced with a low pitch:

> [まつな]{HLL}。"Don't wait!"
>
> [たべるな]{LHLL}。"Don't eat (it)!"
>
> [いくな]{LHL}。"Don't go!"
>
> [みるな]{HLL}。 "Don't look!"
>
> [あきらめるな]{LHHHLL}。"Don't give up!"
>
> [やるな]{LHL}。"Don't do it!"
>
> [するな]{LHL}。"Don't do it!"
>
> [べんきょうするな]{LHHHHHHL}。"Don't study!"

... or maaybe you heard **Kansai-ben** 「待ちいな」(imperative 待ちい + causal end-particle な)?

> [まちい]{LHL}+[な]{L}/[さ]{L}/[や]{L}。"Wait!"
>
> [たべえ]{LHL}+[な]{L}/[さ]{L}/[や]{L}。 "Eat!"
>
> [しい]{HL}+[な]{L}/[さ]{L}。/ [せえ]{HL}+[や]{L}。"Do it!"